# Fundamental matrix and exponential of matrix using Laplace Transform

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, exponential-function

I'm trying to work out how to find $$\exp(At)$$ for a system of linear differential equations $$x'=Ax.$$

I know that the solution is a fundamental matrix of the system such that $$\exp(At)=I$$
 at time $0$.

What is the method for solving this using the Laplace transform?  The only method I can figure out is finding the eigenvalues and diagonalzing the matrix.

Comment: Look at "Nineteen Dubious Ways to
Compute the Exponential of a
Matrix, Twenty-Five Years
Later", Moler & Van Loan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laplace transform of $exp(At)$ is $(sI-A)^{-1}$. So compute that latter and then take its inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: How do you propose to compute $(sI-A)^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes. Then take element wise inverse Laplace transform. What we will have is precisely $exp(At)$.

Comment: Computing that inverse seems to be a nightmare.  You cannot use normal elimination, so how do you compute that inverse in actual problems?

Comment: @Manos: I understand the definition and the formal computation, but practicality is another matter. Just as one almost never inverts a matrix using Cramer's rule.

Comment: Everything depends on what our matrix $A$ is. If $A$ is $3 \times 3$, computing $(sI-A)^{-1}$ is easy. If it is $1000 \times 1000$ it is not. In any case, there is a variety of ways to compute the matrix exponential. The above mentioned article is a good guide.